# Paying myself a distribution caused a negative Owner's Equity account balance? Is this normal?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I just paid out my first distribution from my LLC.  I wrote myself a check for $200 (example), using my business account and selected Owner's Equity.  When I look at my summary of accounts, I notice that my bank account balance decreased by $200, but now I have a negative Owner's Equity balance (-$200.00).  Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not abnormal for a company that is as young as yours seems to be. It seems (based on what little I know), that you have debts, or accounts payable that were formerly covered by the $200 cash, but now aren't, because you paid it to yourself. For now, you're "entitled" to pay yourself a draw or a salary. But if you continue to do so without earning money to cover it, your company will fail.

Comment: I must be booking something wrong because the company has assets (plenty of cash, equipment) and no debt.  The company is very young, yes, but it is very profitable.  I simply took a small amount of money out of the business as a draw.  Is "Owner's Equity" the wrong account maybe?

Comment: Actually, I thought of something else: You will have a lot of "retained earnings" if the company is profitable. That's now part of "owner's equity." It could be that the INITIAL equity was zero (or close to). So $200 might "deplete" initial equity. But in fact, it should come out of retained earnings. This should remain positive, therefore so should total owner's equity.